# error passing TextView values between classes

Tags: java, android, textview

Hi i'm new to android development.... I'm writing an app that will allow the user to enter values and they will be used to plot on a chart. The last few days I have been stuck on a particular problem and can't seem to get over it.
The user will input 2 values and from these 3 values will be calculated and passed to an inner class to be plotted on the chart. These values are of the TextView form. I know most of the code works as i have been testing it, and i'm pretty sure that the error has something to do with the TextView values. Below is the code used for the calculations and drawing the chart.

```
package com.example.ballanimation;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class calculations extends Activity {

EditText firstVal, secondVal;
TextView resultA, resultB, resultC;
Button button3;
BigDecimal firstNum, secNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculations_page);

    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    firstVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTXT1);
    secondVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTXT2);

    resultA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result1);
    resultB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
    resultC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result3);


    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            firstNum = new BigDecimal(firstVal.getText().toString());
            secNum = new BigDecimal(secondVal.getText().toString());
            resultA.setText(firstNum.add(secNum).toString());
            resultB.setText(firstNum.subtract(secNum).toString());
            resultC.setText(firstNum.multiply(secNum).toString());

        }
    });


}

class TestA1 extends View{

    public TestA1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        String TestA = resultA.getText().toString();
        String TestB = resultB.getText().toString();
        String TestC = resultC.getText().toString();

        int A = Integer.parseInt(TestA);
        int B = Integer.parseInt(TestB);
        int C = Integer.parseInt(TestC);

        Paint red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(Color.RED);
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Paint black = new Paint();
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        canvas.drawCircle(A, B, C, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*1/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*475/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*349/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*6/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*228/1000, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()*7/8, canvas.getWidth()*5/8, canvas.getWidth()*103/1000, black);

        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()-canvas.getWidth()) + 10, (canvas.getHeight()*3)/8, canvas.getWidth() - 10, (canvas.getHeight()*3)/8, black);

        float a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l;

        a = 90;   //degrees
        b = 90;
        c = 90;
        d = 50;
        e = 90;
        f = 134;
        g = -90;
        h = -90;
        i = -90;
        j = -50;
        k = -90;
        l = -134;

        RectF arc0 = new RectF();
        RectF arc1 = new RectF();
        RectF arc2 = new RectF();
        RectF arc3 = new RectF();
        RectF arc4 = new RectF();
        RectF arc5 = new RectF();

        /*left  The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle 
        top  The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle 
        right  The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle 
        bottom  The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle  */



        arc0.set(canvas.getWidth()*1/2, canvas.getHeight()*-139/700, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*3/8); 
        arc1.set(canvas.getWidth()*-6/112, canvas.getHeight()*-80/100, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*72/192);   
        arc2.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*70/700, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*3/8); 
        arc3.set(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*100/69, canvas.getHeight()*91/96);
        arc4.set(canvas.getWidth()*-8/112, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*195/100, canvas.getHeight()*150/100);
        arc5.set(canvas.getWidth()*7/10, canvas.getHeight()*3/8, canvas.getWidth()*125/100, canvas.getHeight()*65/100);


        /*oval  The bounds of oval used to define the shape and size of the arc 
        startAngle  Starting angle (in degrees) where the arc begins 
        sweepAngle  Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise 
        useCenter  If true, include the center of the oval in the arc, and close it if it is being stroked. This will draw a wedge 
        paint  The paint used to draw the arc  */

        canvas.drawArc(arc0, a, b, false, red);
        canvas.drawArc(arc1, c, d, false, red);
        canvas.drawArc(arc2, e, f, false, red);
        canvas.drawArc(arc3, g, h, false, red);
        canvas.drawArc(arc4, i, j, false, red);
        canvas.drawArc(arc5, k, l, false, red);

    }
}
```

}

The logcat error's i am getting are:

```
01-04 13:08:46.764: E/Trace(918): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-04 13:08:47.593: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 3% free 8053K/8259K, paused 105ms, total 108ms
01-04 13:08:47.604: I/dalvikvm-heap(918): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.305MB for 412064-byte allocation
01-04 13:08:47.703: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 8454K/8711K, paused 61ms, total 61ms
01-04 13:08:47.764: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 8454K/8711K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
01-04 13:08:47.794: I/dalvikvm-heap(918): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.189MB for 928216-byte allocation
01-04 13:08:47.964: D/dalvikvm(918): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9361K/9671K, paused 98ms+6ms, total 168ms
01-04 13:08:47.964: D/dalvikvm(918): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
01-04 13:08:48.344: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 13:08:48.374: D/gralloc_goldfish(918): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-04 13:08:50.025: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 13:08:56.844: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 13:08:57.514: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
01-04 13:08:57.514: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.ballanimation.calculations$TestA1.onDraw(calculations.java:68)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2256)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 13:08:57.614: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 13:08:59.854: I/Process(918): Sending signal. PID: 918 SIG: 9
01-04 13:09:13.584: E/Trace(960): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-04 13:09:14.364: D/dalvikvm(960): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 3% free 8053K/8259K, paused 73ms, total 76ms
01-04 13:09:14.364: I/dalvikvm-heap(960): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.305MB for 412064-byte allocation
01-04 13:09:14.445: D/dalvikvm(960): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 8454K/8711K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
01-04 13:09:14.494: D/dalvikvm(960): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 8454K/8711K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
01-04 13:09:14.514: I/dalvikvm-heap(960): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.189MB for 928216-byte allocation
01-04 13:09:14.684: D/dalvikvm(960): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9361K/9671K, paused 80ms+18ms, total 162ms
01-04 13:09:15.024: D/gralloc_goldfish(960): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-04 13:09:16.874: I/Choreographer(960): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 13:09:20.643: I/Choreographer(960): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 13:09:32.394: W/ResourceType(960): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000064
01-04 13:09:32.394: D/AndroidRuntime(960): Shutting down VM
01-04 13:09:32.394: W/dalvikvm(960): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.example.ballanimation.calculations$1.onClick(calculations.java:49)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 13:09:34.894: I/Process(960): Sending signal. PID: 960 SIG: 9
```

I'm sorry if this is a lot of information, but i'm really stuck on this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards P

Comment: Change  resultA.setText(firstNum.add(secNum).toString()); to resultA.setText((String)firstNum.add(secNum).toString());

Comment: the method setText() your are using expects string resource id. If above did not help then resultA.setText((CharSequence)firstNum.add(secNum).toString());

Answer (score 2):

Since `View.getText()` never returns `null`, only String  `resultA` , `resultB` or `resultC` can be `null`:

are `R.id.result1`, `R.id.result2`, `R.id.result3` declared inside  `R.layout.calculations_page`?

Comment: Hi ya they are declared in the XML file calculations page. I tried setting the values of resultA, resultB and resultC using resultA.setText(100); so that they could never be null but this seemed to have no effect. Programme was still force closing once I clicked on button to bring me into graph

Comment: @user1927105: Your exception clearly says that one of the resource doesn't exist. `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
at com.example.ballanimation.calculations$1.onClick(calculations.java:49)`

Comment: @ShashankKadne is right. I was stuck on the NPE. Also you can not use setText(100) but should be a valid R.string id or a  String setText("100") for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem lies here

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
01-04 13:09:32.454: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at **com.example.ballanimation.calculations$1.onClick(calculations.java:49)**
```

Just for experiment 
Change your lines

```
 resultA.setText(firstNum.add(secNum).toString());
            resultB.setText(firstNum.subtract(secNum).toString());
            resultC.setText(firstNum.multiply(secNum).toString());
```

To

```
 resultA.setText("234234"));
            resultB.setText("123123");
            resultC.setText("1232122");
```

ANd see the difference

Comment: From the BigDecimal documentation: Returns the string representation of this BigDecimal, using scientific notation if an exponent is needed